# Basic Authentication in Apache Karaf

Tags: java, osgi, cxf, basic-authentication, apache-karaf

I have an `OSGi` bundle which is deployed into `Apache Karaf 2.2.8`. In this bundle I am using `CXF` and `Camel` routes. I written a `CXF` interceptor which does the basic authentication: takes all existing users from database and does validation.

The problem is when the method `handleMessage` is called, the `AuthorizationPolicy` object is null. It does not provides any credentials. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message message)
        throws Fault {
        AuthorizationPolicy policy = message.get(AuthorizationPolicy.class);
    if (users == null) {
        setLastAccessedTime(Calendar.getInstance());
    }
    if (!wasRecentlyAccessed()) {
        users = this.loadUsers();
        setLastAccessedTime(Calendar.getInstance());
    }
    for (String user : users.values()) {
        LOGGER.debug("Existing user: " + user);
    }
    if (policy == null) {
        LOGGER.error("User attempted to log in with no credentials");
        sendErrorResponse(message, HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        return;
    }
    String password = users.get(policy.getUserName());
    if (password == null || !policy.getPassword().equals(password)) {
        LOGGER.error("Invalid login authentication for user: " + policy.getUserName());
        sendErrorResponse(message, HttpURLConnection.HTTP_FORBIDDEN);            
    }
}
```

Is there anyway I can set up the basic authentication parameters in Karaf for the specific endpoint? Is there is some kind of configuration file or something? I can not find anything on the internet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB_Enterprise/7.1/html/Security_Guide/files/CamelJetty-BasicAuth.html

It is explained very clear how to make basic authentication work with `Apache Karaf` and `Camel Jetty`. Later you can use it on every bundle deployed in your `Apache Karaf`.